# unsafeWindow no longer works – What do I do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I'm running a couple of self-written Greasemonkey userscripts that almost always needed the *unsafeWindow* function in some way. Unfortunately, that function has been discontinued for the most part, but now I'm having trouble fixing my scripts. I've read that there are three new functions (*cloneInto()*, *exportFunction()*, and *createObjectIn()*), but I openly admit that I don't get what [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Interacting_with_page_scripts) wants me to do.

Can somebody give me a quick explanation of which of these three functions I should use and of course also how to convert them to work again? I'm sorry, but I'm not very good at this stuff.

As a simple example:

```
$("#someid").append('<a href="#" onclick="somefunction();return false;">Click</a>');

unsafeWindow.somefunction = function() {
    alert("Hello!");
}
```

Comment: That duplicate has pretty much nothing to do with my problem. Either that or I can't seem to find any connection.

Comment: I rater think that it does have to do with your problem ...

Answer (score 0):

Greasemonkey 2.0 radically changed `unsafeWindow` handling. Now you should use

```
unsafeWindow.somefunction = exportFunction(function() {
    alert("Hello!");
}, unsafeWindow);
```

or

```
exportFunction(function() {
    alert("Hello!");
}, unsafeWindow, {defineAs: "somefunction"});
```

See [`exportFunction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Components.utils.exportFunction) in MDN. You may also be interested on [`createObjectIn`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Components.utils.createObjectIn) and [`cloneInto`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Components.utils.cloneInto).

Comment: I said I know of these three functions. What I don't know is how to use them properly. Also, in that code you provided I can't see the name anymore ("somefunction").

Comment: @user3216060 I forgot that part, fixed. What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: Hmm, I still seem to get "ReferenceError: somefunction is not defined". I tried both methods. It's like Firefox/Greasemonkey outright ignore the presence of this function. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: @user3216060 Do you get that error in your GM script or in target page? How do you attempt to use `somefunction`? Are you sure you attempt to use it after exporting it?